# Retrieve multiple parameters (@Param) in NestJS controller gives undefined values

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

I am having trouble retrieving parameters (`@Param()` decorators in the controller.ts) from a NestJS controller when there are defined in the `@Controller()` decorator argument and the `@Get()` argument.

I am new to NestJS so I might have missed something, but could anyone explain to me how getting the `/folder/1/doc/2/file/3` uri is not giving me all the parameters I want ?

Related codesandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/nest-typescript-starter-zbvfw?fontsize=14

```
@Controller('folder/:folderId/other|doc/:docId/file/:fileId')
```

I expect `1 2 3` when I am having `undefined 2 3` when hitting the `/folder/1/doc/2/file/3` uri

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your or-pipe `|` is on top level, meaning either the first part of your URL is interpreted or the last one. You can check the regex produced by your path with [this tool](http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/):

```
/^folder\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/(?:(other|doc))\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/file\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/i
```

Instead you have to put parentheses around your or expression:

```
@Controller('folder/:folderId/:type(other|doc)/:docId/')
```

With this, `type` is another named parameter with two matching values. It will contain either `"other"` or `"doc"`.